# Double covering $SL(2, \mathbb{C}) \to SO^{+}(1,3)$ preserves adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups

Consider the usual double covering $\kappa : SL(2, \mathbb{C}) \to SO^{+}(1,3)$ defined by $\kappa(A)x_{*} = A x_{*} A^{\dagger}$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$ is identified with the $2\times2$ Hermitian matrix $x_{*} = x^0 I + x^1 \sigma_1 + x^2 \sigma_2 + x^3 \sigma_3$ where $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices. In his *Quantum Field Theory* book, Folland claims (p. 71) that $\kappa(A^\dagger) = \kappa(A)^\dagger$ where $A^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ and $\kappa(A)^\dagger$ is the transpose of $\kappa(A)$. Is there a simple way to see this or need one work out a formula for $\kappa(A)$ in terms of the entries of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Given that the $(I, \sigma)$ basis for the space of Hermitian $2 \times 2$ matrices is orthogonal under the trace inner product, it follows that (up to a factor of $2$) the $(j, k)$ entry of $\kappa(A)$ is $\text{tr}(A \sigma_j A^{\dagger} \sigma_k)$ (here I'm using $\sigma_0 = I$). Similarly the $(k, j)$ entry of $\kappa(A^{\dagger})$ is (up to the same factor of $2$) given by $\text{tr}(A^{\dagger} \sigma_k A \sigma_j)$. These are the same due to the ciclicity of the trace, so that $\kappa(A^\dagger)$ is the transpose of $\kappa(A)$.